# Where and how to put Model query methods in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, where-clause

i'm looking for an elegant way to make a model method call. Here is my query:

```
where("order_id = ?", argument).first
```

I can't use this query in a scope, because of the first() method, which is chained after the where() method.

So I tried to create the following class method:

```
  def self.find_order(value)
    where("order_id = ?", value).first
  end
```

When I use this method twice in my controller action, I get a warning from my IDE, that I should move this query into a scope. When I rename the method without 'find' in the beginning, I also get a warning in my controller, that I shouldn't call more than one method besides find() or new() (I have a another model method calling in this controller action). I know, it isn't a real problem because it works, but I'm interested in writing nice and dry code. I hope it isn't an annoying question, I should fairly say that I'm relatively new to programming.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the use case for looking up more than one order in your controller method?

Comment: Just because an IDE tells you something doesn't mean it necessarily makes sense. You can also use `limit`.

Comment: Thank you both. After your reply I noticed, that my controller action actually wasn't really DRY. So now I only need to call that method once.